# Access public Facebook posts for a public page which I own without App Review?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Most of walkthroughs that I can find are all from before recent Facebook regulations.

All of my attempts to use Facebook's api result in my not having access despite the fact that I'm looking for public posts of a public page which I own.

I have figured out how to get the access token

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
```

and with that token I have tried

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

and

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<MY_PAGE>/posts?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

I have also tried using the Facebook JS SDK, which looked like this

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '<APP_ID>',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.2'
    });

    FB.api(
    "/<MY_PAGE>/feed",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you own the Page, you can use a Page Token without any Review. Just authorize yourself with the `manage_pages` permission and use the User Token to get a Page token with this endpoint: `/page-id?fields=access_token` - or for all Pages you manage: `/me/accounts?fields=access_token`

More information about Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: This sounds very promising, I will test tonight. Thank you!